# Why didn't Ben use all the ultimate aliens?

Tags: ben-10

Why didn't Ben Tennyson, use all the ultimate aliens?

Is there a specific reason, or the designers didn't have time to design those characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Ben 10 wikia](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimatrix);

> "Albedo stole the Ultimatrix and was able to stabilize the core, as
>   well as "surpassing" the prototype Omnitrix by adding the evolutionary
>   function. Unfortunately for him, Ben's DNA was still the default for
>   the Omnitrix and the Ultimatrix was still linked to the same database,
>   **so Albedo only had access to Ben's current aliens**"

Although Ban is shown to add and upgrade new alien DNA that he comes into contact with, he mostly uses the ***existing*** upgraded aliens built into the Ultimatrix.

In a [later episode](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_10,000_Returns), we find that Ben has pretty much stopped capturing aliens (pokemon style), having discovered the ability to upgrade himself to "[Ultimate Ben](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Ben)" which he considers to be the "ultimate upgrade".

[image: Ultimate Ben]